# pass object of selenium from a subprocess to another subprocess

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing, queue, multiprocessing-manager

I try to use manager and queue to share the object of selenium in two subprocess, but it shows me the error "AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron..encodekey'"

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from multiprocessing import Queue, Manager, Process
import time

def find(q):
    driver = Chrome()
    driver.get('https://querycourse.ntust.edu.tw/querycourse/api/courses')
    q.put(driver)

def refresh(q):
    driver = q.get()
    while True:
        time.sleep(9)
        driver.refresh()

if __name__=='__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        q = manager.Queue()
        p1 = Process(target=find, args=(q,))
        p2 = Process(target=refresh, args=(q,))
        
        p1.start()
        time.sleep(3)
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\python_training\web crawler\kk_manager_queue.py", line 8, in find
    q.put(driver)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 817, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encodekey'
```

Does any one know what's wrong with my code? Any feetbeck are appreciated.

I simplified the code, I originally expected to use the code grabbing the course I want. One subprocess is to refresh the course selecting system to prevent Connect Timeouts, the other is to detect if someone drops the course and then click the “select” button, so the two subprocesses need to share the object “driver”.

This is my original code:

```
import urllib.request as req
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
from multiprocessing import Manager, Queue, Process

def find(url, requestData, chooseStudent, q):
    while True:
        request=req.Request(url, headers={
            "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }, data=json.dumps(requestData).encode("utf-8"))

        with req.urlopen(request) as response:
            result=response.read().decode("utf-8")

        result=json.loads(result)

        if int(result[0]["ChooseStudent"])<chooseStudent:
            driver = q.get()
            ADDgo = driver.find_element(By.ID, "SingleAdd")
            ADDgo.click()
            break

def refresh(q):
    account='XXXXXXXX'
    password='XXXXXXXX'
    classid='GE3710302'

    driver = Chrome()
    driver.get("https://stuinfosys.ntust.edu.tw/NTUSTSSOServ/SSO/Login/CourseSelection")
    UserName = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.NAME,"UserName"))
    UserName.send_keys(account)
    Password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Password")
    Password.send_keys(password)
    btnLogIn = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "btnLogIn")
    btnLogIn.click()
    q.put(driver)
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.refresh()

if __name__=='__main__':
    url="https://querycourse.ntust.edu.tw/querycourse/api/courses"
    requestData={"Semester":"1112","CourseNo":"GE3710302","CourseName":"","CourseTeacher":"","Dimension":"","CourseNotes":"","ForeignLanguage":0,"OnlyGeneral":0,"OnleyNTUST":0,"OnlyMaster":0,"OnlyUnderGraduate":0,"OnlyNode":0,"Language":"zh"}
    chooseStudent=51
    with Manager() as manager:
        q = manager.Queue()
        p1 = Process(target=find, args=(url, requestData, chooseStudent, q,))
        p2 = Process(target=refresh, args=(q,))

        p1.start()
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

Comment: You could potentially get this going on Linux or Mac (which fork subprocesses) but not on Windows. To get an object to a subprocess, you have to serialize all of its data and rebuild it in the other process. That would be unlikely for an entire instance of a chrome process.

Comment: I don't know the intent of the code, but generally one would pass a URL to a subprocess and let it create the driver and do the work.

Comment: @tdelaney
Actually, I simplified the code, I originally expected to use the code grabbing the course I want. One subprocess is to refresh the course selecting system to prevent Connect Timeouts, the other is to detect if someone drops the course and then click the “select” button, so the two subprocesses need to share the object “driver”. The system I use is windows11, why I can’t run it on windows?

Comment: @tdelaney The original code is edit on above post